# Statistics for correlations with many (0,0) values

Tags: statistics, correlation

Suppose you have a large but finite collection of tweets. You want to know whether talking about football tends to correlate with talking about basketball. You can generate a table for a few hundred users with x's of "NFL" mentions, and y's of "NBA" mentions.  Say, over half of them are (0,0).  I actually have such tables for many word pairs: some graphs look like a messy y=mx, some look as if bounded by y=1/x.

Q: is there any mathematically sound way of describing the statistics, the correlations, when so many values are (0,0)?

Comment: You might get better answers if you post this on Cross Validated, the StackExchange site for questions about statistics: http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Since so many of your values are $(0,0)$, there probably isn't much harm (and maybe some benefit, since some people repeat terms more than others) in just asking for each tweet, "Did they mention NFL?" and "Did they mention NBA?". There are 4 possible combinations of yes/no for these questions. You want to know if the answers to the questions are independent or positively correlated. For that you can consider contingency tables (you can look it up online if you're unfamiliar, wikipedia is good) and then use at least 3 different methods to get a p-value of how unlikely the positive correlation of mentions is by chance: 1) Fischer's exact test 2) Chi-squared approximation 3) (My favorite for your situation) Assume the "yes/yes" count is Poisson with rate given by the product of observed rates of the individual "yes" for each question (i.e., assume independence), and then compute the Poisson p-value for the probability that the "yes/yes" is greater than or equal to the observed value, using the Poisson distribution directly. This is especially a fast and easy and very (VERY) good approximation if the probability of each mention's individual "yes" is very low.

Comment: You may have misunderstood the OP’s question. My understanding is that there is one point $(x,y)$ per *user* (not one point per tweet), where $x$ is the number of times NFL is ever mentioned by that user and $y$ is the number of times NBA is mentioned by that user. The OP wants to know if the number of times a user mentions football is correlated to the number of times a user mentions basketball. Look at http://i.imgur.com/tN8IYys.png, where there are $55$ points at the origin. Correlation suggests a positive relationship, but the graph suggests a negative (or at least more complicated) one.

Comment: @SteveKass Even if that is the case, if the majority of values are $(0,0)$ then under some regularity conditions (basically assuming that "positvie" users tend to mention NFL and NBA approximately equal or positively  linearly related [and expected low] number of times, assuming they are mentioning them in a correlated fashion), then my proposed framework will still work pretty well.

Comment: I think your proposed framework will “work,” but it will work to answer a rather different question than the OP has. Your framework will be sensitive to the disparity between tweets that mention both NBA and NFL vs. tweets that mention only one (or neither). The OP doesn’t care about that distinction, it seems to me. The OP cares about people who tweet, not tweets. Your framework will not be sensitive to whether those tweets that mention NFL only and those tweets that mention NBA only are from the same person, but the OP cares about that. I may be wrong, and hope the OP clears this up.

Comment: @SteveKass Still my framework could be adapted to a user-based approach, where for each user either they mention NFL at least once (or a certain percentage of the time) in tweets, or not, and similarly for NBA. This would still give a contingency table approach, except this time according to users. In a certain sense this may be more desirable, if a tweeter-based model is adopted (instead of individual tweet-based), because some users may tweet about NBA and NFL all the time, and it seems dubious to let very active tweeters dominate the analysis just because they tweet more frequently.

Comment: I think it’s important to formulate a clear question before developing a framework and calculating some statistics. I can’t tell what clear question your framework answers, but I don’t think it answers the OP’s question, which seems to be to quantify the relationship between two variables in a sample of Twitter users. The variables described by the OP are x=(user’s number of NFL mentions) and y=(user’s number of NBA mentions). There are no doubt other interesting questions to explore from the available data, and your suggestion may address them.

Comment: @SteveKass The clear question that my second suggestion answers is whether there is a positive correlation between a user ever mentioning NFL and ever mentioning NBA (over all users), or alternatively whether there is a positive correlation between a user mentioning NFL X% of the time and NBA Y% of the time. Both lead to contingency table approaches, just like original individual tweet-based approach. If the relative % (or count) of NFL mentions per user vs. relative % or count of NBA mentions is of interest, then I think there are too many ways to formulate the problem without more OP input.

Comment: Well put. I hope the OP adds something or posts on Cross Validated.